# Android Wear samples fail in Android Studio 2.3 betas and RC1

Tags: android, android-studio, wear-os

I have updated Android Studio to the various 2.3 beta versions and finally RC1. When opening my existing projects, Studio offered to update them to Gradle 2.3.0-rc1 and then displays incompatibility within my wearable Gradle script.

For verification I have imported the SDK sample project "GridViewPager" and got the same problem, Any idea on how to fix this or should it just be ignored?

Incompatibility message for unmodified SDK sample:

[image: Android Studio Screnshot]

Comment: You should show your entire Gradle file as *text*, not an image, please

Comment: Just import the "GridViewPager" SDK sample project which you will find within Studio samples list below the "wearable" label and you can reproduce by yourself. I have included a screenshot of the unmodified sample code to show you the popup message which cannot be copied as plain text.

Comment: Well, as the error hints, you seem to have version mismatches. I don't use Android Studio, so please show your Gradle file